# `eslint-env` failed to prevent `no-undef` to raise errors on `console`, `window` or `process`, `export`

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser, eslint

title says it all.

My project is a simple Node.js server, so it includes both Node.js and Browser environment.

Add Globals to `eslint.config.js` might cause underreporting.

But `/* eslint-env browser */` or `/* eslint-env node */` doesn't take effect.

When I write `/* eslint-env browser */`, I was expecting ESLint to prevent raising errors on `console` and `window`

When I write `/* eslint-env node */`, I was expecting ESLint to prevent raising errors on `process` and `export`

my `eslint.config.js`:

```js
import {FlatCompat} from '@eslint/eslintrc';

// extension rule sets
import jsdoc from 'eslint-plugin-jsdoc';
import js from '@eslint/js';
// import "eslint-config-google"

// Compat Function with Dynamic `__DirName` environment variable
import {dirname} from 'desm';
const compat = new FlatCompat({
  get baseDirectory() {
    return dirname(import.meta.url);
  },
  get resolvePluginsRelativeTo() {
    return dirname(import.meta.url);
  }
});

/** @type {import('eslint').Linter.FlatConfig[]} */
export default [
  js.configs.recommended, // eslint:recommended
  jsdoc.configs['flat/recommended'], // plugin:jsdoc/recommended
  ...compat.extends('google'), // compat old "Google JS Style Guide" Config
  {
    languageOptions: {
      ecmaVersion: 2022,
      sourceType: 'module',
    },
    rules: {
      'multiline-comment-style': 'error',
    },
  },
];
```

I think I need to provide additional information, but I don't know what to provide. If you need more infomation, please let me know.